# Can' log in with Cyrillic keyboard

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-layout

On my Windows 7 OS I have set the login password which contains a 'q' character. The problem is that I accidentally installed Windows with default Serbian Cyrillic characters. I found out that this alphabet doesn't have a 'q' letter. Is there some way out of this because I can't login into my PC?

Comment: Can't you use the on-screen keyboard?

Comment: You have only Serbian input language installed? Or you have other languages also?

Comment: The on screen keyboard is cyrillic

Comment: I have others, but it appears that it only recognizes Cyrillic at startup

Comment: Can you toggle through the available keyboards with <Right Alt>+<Shift> on the log on screen ?

Comment: No, this doesn't work. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You may "type" `q` character from NumPad. Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and press <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>3</kbd>. 113 is ASCII equivalent of `q` character.

May be <kbd>NumLock</kbd> toggle will be required, or Left/Right <kbd>Alt</kbd> must be used in your case.

Note! This will not work from on screen keyboard and may fails on notebook keyboard - "real" numpad is required.

Comment: Good solution, but I have a notebook.

Comment: Attach USB keyboard and use it.

Comment: Otherwise, I believe, you need to reunstall/update your windows installation. But... may be you may boot into recovery console and it will be "English" input by default? Not sure.

Comment: Another thought, notebooks may emulate NumPad you you turn `NumLock` on. Try it, may be you'll be lucky.

Comment: I tried alt+113 and it won't recognize it (tried on desktop and it worked). External keyboard also didn't worked. I will try with the Windows CD...